# Can anyone tell me more about this Prediction quality measure, Prediction Accuracy, used for regression evaluation?

Tags: regression, python, prediction, goodness-of-fit

I am trying to find more info about the attached Prediction Accuracy measure used for regression. It is quiet similar to R2 and Nash-sutcliffe Efficiency but not exactly. Googling leads to classification accuracy measures, which is wrong.

Any links, sources or info about the measure is appreciated. Also, is there an API to implement it directly in Python?

Also, the highest possible value with PA is 1 but the output of the formula gives any value as can be seen in this code, or is the code wrong?

```
y_value = [2,4,6,5,8,10]
y_value_test = [1,3,6,7,9,11]

y_value_bar = np.mean(y_value)
y_value_test_bar = np.mean(y_value_test) 

upper = np.sum(y_value - y_value_bar)
lower = np.sum(y_value_test - y_value_test_bar)

result = upper/lower
result
```

[image]

Comment: Can you give any context? I assume the indices are for instances, but what are the $P$s and the $O$s? Where did you find this measure? Is it a goodness of fit measure (measured in-sample), or a prediction quality measure (measured out-of-sample)?

Comment: It is a prediction quality measure. P is for predicted and O for observed. It´s taken from this paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1309104215000136

Comment: I updated and added code aswell

Comment: Thanks for your updates, it's much clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll be honest. This KPI is utter crap. And I would have written the same over my name if I had been a reviewer for the paper.

The denominator $\sum_{i=1}^N(O_i-\bar{O})$ does not depend on the predictions, so it's just a normalizing factor. Let's leave it aside for now.

The numerator $\sum_{i=1}^N(P_i-\bar{P})$ is... well, it's nothing at all, beyond being the average difference between the predictions and the average prediction. So you could call it a kind of Mean Error... but "Error" typically indicates some kind of relationship between the predictions and the *actuals*, and there is no such relationship here - it's an "error" between the predictions and the average prediction. Why anyone would be interested in this quantity is beyond me.

Now, if we simply scale each $P_i$ by a constant $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, then we scale $\bar{P}$, therefore the entire numerator, and therefore $PA$, by the same $\alpha$. So we can make $PA$ as large or as small (even negative) as we want. There is still no relationship between $\alpha PA$ and any kind of prediction accuracy. In particular, there is no reason at all to claim that "a higher accuracy is given by a value closer to 1" (section 3.6 in the paper). (Actually, since there is so utterly no connection between $PA$ and a value 1, I slightly suspect that the authors actually used some other formula, and that their equation (6) reflects something else than the $PA$ they report.)

The authors' confusion may stem from the fact that if $P_i=O_i$ for all $i$, then yes, $PA=1$. But we want to argue the other way around: if $PA=1$, then the predictions are "good" in some way, $P_i\approx O_i$. And that simply doesn't follow. It might as well be that $P_i=O_i+K$ for some constant $K\in\mathbb{R}$, which again yields $PA=1$, but we hopefully wouldn't call all predictions equally "good" that differed from the observations by some (possibly large) offset. Or the predictions might be equal to the observations - but permuted randomly, $P_i=O_{\pi(i)}$ for some random permutation $\pi$. This would again yield $PA=1$, but would hopefully not be considered a good prediction.

Bottom line: disregard $PA$ completely, and definitely don't use this in any follow-up work. Concentrate on the more reasonable error measures they also use, like the $NAE$ and the $RMSE$. (Actually, it makes no sense to use *both* error measures to evaluate the *same* point prediction, per [Kolassa, 2020, *IJF*](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijforecast.2019.02.017). Yes, that's me.)

Comment: I agree with your input Stephan Kolassa, thank you!